# How to force Windows always treat all Ethernet (wired) connections as "Private" networks?

Tags: windows-10, private-network

Is there a way to force Windows to always treat all Ethernet (wired) networks as private networks?

I don't want to do this manually and I don't want this to affect Wi-Fi or other types of connections.

Comment: I don't think this is possible automatically.  Manual at first, but then automated solution: You might be able to write a PowerShell script using `Set-NetConnectionProfile` and attach a Scheduled Task to a particular Event Log ID (such as when a wired connection is plugged in).

Comment: @asheroto: Good idea! Feel free to post an answer. (Or otherwise I'll post one if I get the chance to write this.)